# Regex to capture string inside parenthesis

Tags: regex

I have tried

```
[^\(]\(.*\)
```

but in a string like

```
Tamara(PER) Jorquiera
```

The pattern returns

```
a(PER)
```

How can I get only the text inside parenthesis, assuming the open and close parenthesis occur once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use following regex :

```
\(([^)]*?)\)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gK5nG3/1)

Note that you don't need `[^\(]` out side of the parenthesis just use 
`[^)]*?` within a capture group.

`[^)]*?` is a non-greedy regex that match anything except closing parenthesis.

Answer (score 1):

> `[^\(]\(.*\)`

It matches any character that is not `(` (`a` in the example).. and a literal `(` then everything till `)`

You can use the following:

```
\([^)]*\)          // this will match only the text between parentheses
                   // including parantheses
```

If you want only the text use lookahead and lookbehinds:

```
(?<=\()[^)]*(?=\))
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/jG5gQ6/1)